# Wordpress page title repeated in SOME pages

Tags: database, wordpress, seo

I have created a Wordpress site and titles were working just fine. Then, some time and plugins installed later, I noticed that in SOME pages I get the title repeated 2 times.

Example of wrong page title:
**Contact - NAME | NAME**

Example of normal title:
**Our Services | NAME**

Now, if I go to General Settings and change title it will change both, no improvement. SEO by Yoast has the option to reset page titles, but that just removes all titles leaving the current URL as page title, so no good either.

Here is the code I originally had:
`<title><?php wp_title(''); ?><?php if(wp_title('', false)) { echo ' | '; } ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>`

Here is the code I am using now:
`<title><?php wp_title('|'); ?></title>`

**To sum up, I think somewhere in the database there's a wp_title repeated: once using '-' as separator, another one (the current one) using '|'.**

Any help will be most appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you have seo plugins installed?

Comment: Yes, I do have Yoast SEO plugin installed. No other.

Comment: Which plugin do you have installed?

Comment: I just said it, it's called ['Wordpress SEO by Yoast'](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/)

Answer (score 1):

SEO Yoast recommends using `<?php wp_title(''); ?>` not `<?php wp_title('|'); ?>`

Check the following:
Login into your admin section and view the offending page.  Under the Wordpress SEO by Yoast metabox check the field 'seo title' to see if the name has been duplicated there.

Under the SEO menu item navigate to titles and metas.

In the general tab check the following:

Is force rewrite titles checked?

Under the post types tab

Check the pages title template to see if it has been duplicated there